# ¿Como evitar el borrar los datos del formulario al enviarlos en un POST?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php5, codeigniter-3

Hola **tengo un formulario y quiero mantener la informacion que capture en los inputs** ya que al enviar la información se borra y hay que estar constantemente haciendo el llenando en los inputs y **quiero mantener la informacion**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <label for="">Servidor</label>
     <input type="text" id="servidor" name="servidor"    
     placeholder="Selecciona el servidor deseado"   >

  <label >Configuracion </label>
  <input type="text"id="configuracion" name="configuracion" placeholder="Selecciona la configuracion deseada"> 
  <button type="submit"  value="registrar" name="boton" id="boton"class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Puedes guardar los datos en una cookie o en una base de datos.

Comment: pero no es posible mantenerlos en el formulario declarando el valor enviado en algun value? o como seria con cookie si me apoyas te lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías ayudarte con variables de sesion, por ejemplo:

En tu controlador donde llega el post:

```
$_SESSION['servidor'] = $_POST['servidor'];
$_SESSION['configuracion'] = $_POST['configuracion'];
```

En tu vista en los imputs:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <label for="">Servidor</label>
     <input type="text" id="servidor" name="servidor"    
     placeholder="Selecciona el servidor deseado" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['servidor'] ?? '' ?>"  >

  <label >Configuracion </label>
  <input type="text"id="configuracion" name="configuracion" placeholder="Selecciona la configuracion deseada" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['configuracion'] ?? '' ?>" > 
  <button type="submit"  value="registrar" name="boton" id="boton"class="btn btn-primary">Registrar</button>
  </form>
```

el **??** esta disponible a partir de la versión 7.1 de php si mal no recuerdo y es el equivalente al isset, en caso de que no lo tengas disponible usa el **isset**

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Al mandar los valores por POST después de haber dado click en el boton submit estos se van a guarda en la variable $_POST, solo tienes que comprobar que existan en esa variable, y es tan simple como hacer esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Formulario extenso</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <script src="funciones/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  
  <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
  <div id="ocultado">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){ echo $_POST['nombre'];} ?>" placeholder="tu nombre aqui">
  <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
  <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">
  <label for="empresa">Empresa:</label>
  <input type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" >
  <br>
  <label for="SE">Software Especializado:</label>
  <select multiple name="mul[]" id="SE" size="3" >
   <option value="ACROBAT READER">ACROBAT READER</option>
   <option value="WINRAR">WINRAR</option>
   <option value="WINZIP">WINZIP</option>

  </select>

  <input type="radio" name="programadores" value="LUIS">
  <input type="radio" name="programadores" value="VICTOR">
  <br>
 </div>
  <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">mandar</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: acabo de implementar lo que me comentas pero no lo guarda  te muestro como lo agregue tal cual:

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="servidor" name="servidor"   value="<?php if(isset($_POST['servidor'])){ echo $_POST['servidor'];}?>" placeholder="Selecciona el servidor deseado">

Comment: A mi me funciona perfecto, tuve un error en la apertura de las etiquetas php, pero en el comentario que me haces están bien, debería funcionar, revisa comillas dobles y simples en el atributo value o qué es lo que no hace?

Comment: lo que no hace es que al momento de registrar el campo se  resetea y se pierde la informacion

Comment: crees que me puedas pasar tu ejemplo para ver como funciona y ver cual es mi posible error ? te lo agradeceria bastante porque implemente esto pero no me funciona

Comment: Disculpa la demora en contestar, ya edite mi respuesta, ese ejemplo estoy utilizando y me va bien, espero te sirva.